# what's the point of creating prototype chain when we've already had Object.prototype.use(object) in JS?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-chain

I've been learning about prototype in Javascript from a Pluralsight course. And I have some confusion about it.

Here's the example. I have 2 constructors Person and Student:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, age) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.age = age;

  this.getFullName = function() {
    console.log(this.firstName + this.lastName)
  }
}

function Student(firstName, lastName, age) {
  this._enrolledCourses = [];

  this.enroll = function (courseId) {
    this._enrolledCourses.push(courseId);
  };

  this.getCourses = function () {
    return this._enrolledCourses;
  };
}
```

Then create an instance of Student:

```
let michael = new Student("Michael", "Nguyen", 22);
```

Now, in the tutorial, it says that in order for `michael` to inherit everything from `Person`, there are 2 steps:

- Step 1: Create prototype chain:

```
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```

- Step 2: call `Person` inside `Student`:

```
function Student(firstName, lastName, age) {
  Person.call(this, firstName, lastName, age); <---- this line

  this._enrolledCourses = [];

  this.enroll = function (courseId) {
    this._enrolledCourses.push(courseId);
  };

  this.getCourses = function () {
    f;
    return this._enrolledCourses;
  };
}
```

However, if I remove step 1 and only follow with step 2, the result remains the same. `michael` is still able to inherit everything from `Person`. The thing is, what's the point of step 1 anyway? If I remove step 2 and only get along with step 1, `michael` won't be able to inherit anything from `Person`.

FYI, here's the course url: *https://app.pluralsight.com/course-player?clipId=f1feb535-bbdd-4255-88e3-ed7079f81e4e*

Comment: Step 1 is important when you define methods on the prototype, which you haven't done.

Comment: _"...when we've already had Object.prototype.use(object) in JS?"_ - There's no such thing? Neither in your question nor in the [spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object)

Comment: The example works with just the 2nd step (the `super` call) because **`Person` does not implement any prototypal method**; the `getFullName` method, implemented within the constructor, gets assigned as an instance's own property. In my opinion the entire example is not well chosen anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your constructors are adding all the properties to `this`, you're not using the prototypes.

Normally, methods are added to the prototype, not each instance, e.g.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, age) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
  console.log(this.firstName + this.lastName)
}
```

If you don't create the prototype chain, `Student` won't inherit a method defined this way.

Comment: I would change it to ... _Methods which have to access locally scoped constructor data are the only ones that have to be implemented within the constructor function. Any other method should be exclusively implemented as prototypal method._

Comment: @PeterSeliger As far as I'm concerned, the first group should normally be empty. Constructor data should be saved in operator properties, which methods can then access. I don't see the need for a more detailed answer to this basic question.

Comment: And I did say "normally". Exceptions are for more advanced programmers.

Comment: The comment was mainly meant for the OP. It was not a critique to @Barmar 's answer.